# “Naming names”: Descriptive or redundant?

Tags: phrases

The phrase *naming names* arises often during the reporting of corruption investigations, political scandals or the like. The word *naming* is defined as citing by name or giving a name to. I could not think of any similarly redundant phrase for comparison.

Is this phrase merely an alliterative embellishment, or does it say more than a replacement phrase such as *naming of implicated individuals* would imply?

Comment: See Strunk&White Rule #4: ***Place a comma before a conjunction  introducing an independent clause.***

Comment: I think the most common context is when people say things like *"I don't want to name names, but we all know there's corruption afoot"*. Which is just a florid/idiomatic way of saying *"I don't want to name **anybody** [that I know/suspect to be guilty]"*. A matter of style, rather than some subtle nuance of meaning.

Comment: To expand a bit on FF's comment, this is just one example of how the language can be used in creative _not-exactly-perfectly-correct-but-not-really-incorrect-either_ ways that are colorful, evocative, and efficient. Moreover, this usage adds a nice implication that the speaker just might be privy to inside information, and that the listener is privileged to receive this special information in a semi-confidential way.

Answer (score 1):

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/name_25) agrees with your supposition that *naming names* means *naming of implicated individuals*:

> **name names**
>
> to state publicly the names of people involved in something dishonest
>   or illegal

Other sources note that *name names* is an **[idiom](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/name-names)**; you can play the same game with other words, but the resulting phrases would be more literal in meaning:

- link links (link hyperlinks, naturally)
- game games (rig or otherwise cheat at games)
- like likes (enjoy your accumulated upvotes on Facebook)

There are many other such examples.

Comment: On the other hand, "I am now going to name names: X, Y and Z" isn't as likely to end one up in a libel case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's sense 4 in the definition that I [cited](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/name_25).

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs (in at least some of their senses) take (perhaps only) objects that are etymologically related to the verb: **cognate objects**.

> **cognate object** (noun) [Grammar]:  a substantive functioning as the object
> of a verb, especially of a verb that is usually intransitive, when
> both object and verb are derived from the same root.

( http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cognate+object )

Thus you can only dream – a dream. You can *dance a dance* or *sing a song*, but here hyponymous objects are also possible – *dance a tango*; *sing a lullaby*. *Sing a song* sounds a lot better than *dance a dance*, of course, but it's just a matter of prosody. Variants on *naming names* don't sound too bad nowadays because they've become accepted usages. Of course, *name*, unlike *dream* or *dance*, is transitive.