# Is there a term for when the verb and the object it is acting upon are the same word?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

Examples:

- I can throw a good throw.
- I want to run a long run today.
- Scoop me a scoop, please.
- She gave me drinks to drink.

I really like these simple sorts of sentences, but I've never seen any specific term for them.

Comment: Repetition, assonance….?

Comment: *Matchmaker, Matchmaker, / Make me a match, / Find me a find, / Catch me a catch*

Comment: The answer is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/438025) (cognate object).

Comment: This is a good question. "Alliteration" refers to consecutive words with similar starting sounds - *over the cobbles he clattered and clashed*. I agree that there ought to be a similar term for what you describe but I'm afraid I don't know what it is.

Comment: _Talk the talk, walk the walk, punch the punch,_ etc. are cognate objects, where the verb and its noun are closely related. A similar but less limited phenomenon is to use small verbs like _do_ with object nouns cognate or related to verbs: _do the dishes/laundry/planning_, etc.

Comment: There are also hyponymic objects, such as sing a carol; dance a tango.

Comment: Those are polysemes — two meanings but a shared etymology. Compare e.g. *bat* (to hit a ball) and *bat* (a stick to hit a ball). Then compare the homonyms *bat* (a stick to hit a ball) and *bat* (the winged mammal). Those aren’t polysemes. Just to confuse things, some would call the first pair above “polysemous homonyms.”